# Nested ## operator in C Preprocessor

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, string-concatenation

**Case 1)**

```
#define CONCATENATE(x,y) x##y
```

**CONCATENATE(a,CONCATENATE(b,c))** gives aCONCATENATE(b,c).

**Case 2)**

```
 #define CONCATENATE(x,y) x##y
 #define CONCATENATE2(x,y) CONCATENATE(x,y)
```

**CONCATENATE2(a,CONCATENATE2(b,c))** gives abc.

Why does *case 1*  doesn't work? And *case 2* does?
Please explain through step-by-step procedure.

Comment: Did you mean the second use case to be: `CONCATENATE2(a, CONCATENATE2(b, c))`?

Comment: @RSahu Yes I did, I edited the question accordingly.Thanks for heads-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GCC docs explain it this way:

> Macro arguments are completely macro-expanded before they are
>   substituted into a macro body, *unless they are stringified or pasted
>   with other tokens*.

(emphasis added)

The operands of the ## (token pasting) operator, on the other hand, are not macro-expanded before being pasted together.  So, given

```
CONCATENATE(a,CONCATENATE(b,c))
```

the preprocessor does not expand `CONCATENATE(b,c)` before expanding the outer macro's body because it is an operand of ##.  The preprocessor instead performs token pasting before rescanning for more macros to expand, so

```
a ## CONCATENATE(b,c)
```

becomes

```
aCONCATENATE(b,c)
```

before the rescan, and there is no macro aCONCATENATE (but if there were, then *it* would be expanded).

On the other hand, with

```
CONCATENATE2(a,CONCATENATE2(b,c)),
```

the argument `CONCATENATE2(b,c)` is not an operand of the ## (or #) operator, so it is expanded before being substituted into the macro body, ultimately yielding

```
CONCATENATE(a, bc)
```

as the first expansion of the outer macro.  That is rescanned for further expansions, yielding

```
abc
```

Answer (score 2):

When macros are used in a self-referential way (or circularly), like you have for `CONCATENATE`, they are not recursively expanded. That's why:

`CONCATENATE(a,CONCATENATE(b,c))` gives `aCONCATENATE(b,c)`.

In the second case, the expansion of `CONCATENATE2` is carried out after `CONCATENATE` is processed. Hence, you get the right output.

Self-referential usages of macros work fine for most cases. The exceptions are token pasting and stringification.

For example, if you have:

```
#define #define foo(x) int x
```

then,

```
foo(foo(x));
```

expands to:

```
int int x;
```

If you have:

```
#define STR(y) #y
```

then,

```
STR(STR(abcd));
```

expands to:

```
"STR(abcd)";
```

More details:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification

[How does the C preprocessor handle circular dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177503/how-does-the-c-preprocessor-handle-circular-dependencies/24177657#24177657)

Comment: The question is not about stringification, it's about token pasting.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, stringification is only an example of using two layers of macros to achieve the right macro expansion and token pasting.

Comment: Ok, but the answer is nevertheless mistaken: a self-referrential macro is one where the macro name appears in its *definition*, not among its arguments.  It works to recurse via arguments, as can be tested pretty easily.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I didn't say the macro is self-referential. I said it's used in self referential way.

Comment: it is true that when a macro's name appears within its definition, *those* apparent self-references are not expanded.  HOWEVER, that rule does not apply when a macro *argument* contains a reference to the called macro.  Normally in those cases, the argument IS expanded.  Example: given `#define foo(x) int x`, `foo(foo(x))` expands to `int int x`, not `int foo(x)`.  Try it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, thanks for clarifying. I looked up on the subject a bit more and updated my answer.