# Can I use token-pasting to handle compile-time naming?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Suppose I have a file I can `#include` that defines something like this:

```
#define GROUP_NUMBER_FOO 42
#define GROUP_NUMBER_BAR 37
```

I would like to `#define` a macro that if invoked like this

```
GROUPID(FOO)(x);
GROUPID(BAR)(x);
```

is transformed to

```
GROUP42_ELEMENT_FOO(x);
GROUP37_ELEMENT_BAR(x);
```

I am hoping this can be done with token-pasting (as in [Nested ## operator in C Preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26284393/nested-operator-in-c-preprocessor) or [How to concatenate twice with the C preprocessor and expand a macro as in "arg ## _ ## MACRO"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/how-to-concatenate-twice-with-the-c-preprocessor-and-expand-a-macro-as-in-arg)) but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Something like

```
#define EXTRACT_GROUP(name) GROUP_NUMBER_##name
#define GROUPID(name) GROUP##EXTRACT_GROUP(name)##_ELEMENT_##name
```

but if I try using `GROUPID(FOO)` then I get an error:

```
 error: pasting ")" and "_ELEMENT_" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

(Before someone says "XY problem!" I have some existing awkward APIs I'm trying to adapt to in a more sensible way.)

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I stumbled my way through it; it looks like I need to add an extra level of indirection:

```
#define GROUP_NUMBER_FOO 42
#define GROUP_NUMBER_BAR 37

#define CONCAT(x,y) x##y
#define EVALCAT(x,y) CONCAT(x,y)
#define CONCAT4(x,y,z,w) x##y##z##w
#define EVALCAT4(x,y,z,w) CONCAT4(x,y,z,w)
#define EXTRACT_GROUP(name) CONCAT(GROUP_NUMBER_,name)
#define GROUPID(name) EVALCAT4(GROUP,EXTRACT_GROUP(name),_ELEMENT_,name)

GROUPID(FOO)
GROUPID(BAR)
```

which gets transformed to the desired

```
GROUP42_ELEMENT_FOO
GROUP37_ELEMENT_BAR
```